# Rooting Samsung Grand Duos without Windows

Tags: rooting, 4.2-jelly-bean, samsung-galaxy-grand-2

I need to root my Samsung GT-I9082 (also known as Grand Duos) with Android 4.2.2 but I have no Windows computer (I have a Linux one).

Which are the preferred methods?

It seems z4root does nothing (seems just to crash).

Answer (score 1):

Towelroot supports most Samsung devices. Based on a quick Google search, it sounds like it has been confirmed to work on GT-I9082. It's extremely simple:

1. Navigate to [towelroot.com](https://towelroot.com/) on the mobile device.
2. Tap the big red lambda (λ) to download the APK file.
3. Find the APK file, either in the notifications or the Download folder, and tap it to install the app.
4. Open the app and tap the <kbd>make it ra1n</kbd> button.

That's it. You should get a message within about 5-10 seconds telling you that you have root access. You don't need a PC, and you don't even need to power off or reboot. It's so simple it's dangerous, because one doesn't need to have a modicum of technical ability in order to gain root access.

Comment: It says "This phone isn't currently supported"

Comment: Since I was able to google up several references for using Towelroot on this model, I suspect that it's your firmware version that's not supported. I've seen this message when trying to use Towelroot on an S4 with the most recent firmware update (NG6). The workaround is to downgrade to previous version of the firmware, run Towelroot, then upgrade back to NG6, but I'm not sure if that would work for your device.

Comment: I've also read [this article about forcing Towelroot to run anyway](http://droidguru.org/how-to-fix-towelroot-phone-isnt-supported-issue/). I haven't tried it myself yet, but I plan on trying it out to root NG6 firmware without the downgrade trick. I'll come back and report my results. BTW, be very careful if you want to try out the firmware downgrade trick, because it can be dangerous. I wouldn't recommend it unless you have a nandroid backup or use a separate device for testing.

Comment: Tried the towelroot article. None of the strings worked. And no downgrade possible, it came with 4.2.2 from factory.