# How to resize partitions when /system isn't mounted in recovery

Tags: recovery-mode, shell, partitions

I have a Runbo X5-King phone which is manufactured by a small Chinese company. I need to shrink /system and expand /data. All tutorials I can find online say to run fdisk in recovery, but the problem is that /system doesn't seem to mount, and "adb shell" results in an error message saying that it cannot find /system/bin/sh. However after booting into Android everything works perfectly, and /system is mounted successfully as well. I'm able to enter fastboot and let my computer interact with the phone, but fastboot doesn't have the ability to resize partitions or enter the shell. Since the phone is not famous, no custom recoveries could be found for it. So how can I resize partitions under this situation?

Comment: I would highly recommend against re-partitioning your phone! Most bootloaders are hard-coded to recognize specific partitions based on their start and end blocks. If you modify these via partitioning, you may end up bricking your device. You should _only_ re-partition if this has been confirmed to work on your particular device.

Comment: Here's my df result:

Comment: app_70@android:/ $ df
Filesystem             Size   Used   Free   Blksize
/dev                   488M    52K   488M   4096
/mnt/asec              488M     0K   488M   4096
/mnt/obb               488M     0K   488M   4096
/system                602M   290M   311M   4096
/data                  502M   399M   103M   4096
/cache                 405M     6M   398M   4096
/mnt/sdcard              7G     5G     1G   32768
/mnt/secure/asec: Permission denied
/mnt/sdcard2             1G     1G     5M   4096
1|app_70@android:/ $

Comment: The default partitioning greatly affects my use of the phone.

Answer (score 1):

To use fdisk without recovery, i.e. while Android is running, you need to root your phone, install a [terminal emulator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm), and install [BusyBox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=stericson.busybox) (the fdisk command won't be available without BusyBox, which provides a bundle of common Linux tools that aren't included in Android). Note that to install BusyBox, it's not sufficient just to install the app. You need to launch the app and click the <kbd>Install</kbd> button in order to install the tools.

The process of rooting is device-dependent, and I don't know specifically how to do it on your device, but you could try Towelroot, which works on a wide variety of Android devices and is [incredibly simple to use](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/86328/58269).

Comment: I have terminal emulator and busybox installed already. But as fdisk is a "partition manager", I don't think it can be used to modify the partitions that are being used on the phone.